# How to remove "this question" and punctuate the sentence "Answer this question ..."

Tags: punctuation, imperatives

In the sentence "Answer this question, what is eleven times nine?" How can I remove "this question", punctuate properly, and still keep the imperative "Answer".

How about: "Answer this: what is eleven times nine?"

Comment: Can you say a bit more about why you want to remove 'question' please? Is it just for the sake of brevity, for example?

Comment: I'd certainly not use a comma in either of your versions. You're allowed to use a capital after a colon where what follows is a sentence. / 'Give the answer to _eleven times nine_.' works.

Comment: Yes just for sake of brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to remove the "this question" part, you should consider...

What is the answer of eleven times nine?

"Answer this: what is eleven times nine?" works as well, yet it does not sound as smooth.